# Getting data from PHP page on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, get

I have **index.php** with a form. When it gets submitted I want the result from **process.php** to be displayed inside the result div on **index.php**. Pretty sure I need some kind of AJAX but I'm not sure...

**index.php**

```
<div id="result"></div>

<form action="" id="form" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" maxlength="16">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

$result = $_GET['q'];

if($result == "Pancakes") {
    echo 'Result is Pancakes';
}

else {
    echo 'Result is something else';
}

?>
```

Comment: If you are pretty sure about AJAX (which is the way to do it) then read a bit about it. Google `AJAX` at least :)

Comment: what you have tried yet for AJAX?try to use AJAX and than tell us the problem.

Comment: [**Google show result in div form php**](https://www.google.ca/search?q=show+result+in+div+form+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr)

Comment: I don't wanna make this as an answer because it's trivial, but if you read this http://api.jquery.com/load/ you will be able to do it in a single line (or 2-3 lines if you want it on click)

Comment: @Dexa Probably wouldn't matter anyway, given the OP's track record, never accepted any answers. So yours is just as good as the others.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't "need" AJAX for this because you can submit it to itself and include the process file:

**index.php**

```
<div id="result">
    <?php include('process.php'); ?>
</div>

<form action="index.php" id="form" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" maxlength="16">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
// Check if form was submitted
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

    $result = $_GET['q'];

    if($result == "Pancakes") {
        echo 'Result is Pancakes';
    }

    else {
        echo 'Result is something else';
    }
}
?>
```

Implementing AJAX will make things more user-friendly but it definitely complicates your code. So good luck with whatever route you take!

This is a jquery Ajax example,

```
<script>
//wait for page load to initialize script
$(document).ready(function(){
    //listen for form submission
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
      //prevent form from submitting and leaving page
      e.preventDefault();

      // AJAX goodness!
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET", //type of submit
            cache: false, //important or else you might get wrong data returned to you
            url: "process.php", //destination
            datatype: "html", //expected data format from process.php
            data: $('form').serialize(), //target your form's data and serialize for a POST
            success: function(data) { // data is the var which holds the output of your process.php

                // locate the div with #result and fill it with returned data from process.php
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You had `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` that did not work. I changed it to `if(isset($_GET['submit'])){` and now it works.

Comment: Your `type: "POST",` will most probably need to be set to `type: "GET",` in your Ajax method.

Comment: Now, what if someone were to enter "pancakes" instead of "Pancakes"? ;-)

Comment: Haha, I need some more coffee!

Comment: That's a big **"10-4"** (no extra chars. required) ;-)

Comment: Seeing that the OP's not making up his/her mind, am going to upvote your answer, because, well... it works. Cheers

Comment: I think a lot of people are on here simply trying to do homework or quizzes anyways especially since some schools have begun classes. Oh well :) I appreciate the upvote, cheers!

Comment: Aahh school! of course. Yeah I figure we'll be seeing a lot of those, I'm waitin' for 'em! lol and you're welcome, cheers

Answer (score 1):

this is jquery Ajax example,

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somescript.php",
        datatype: "html",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            doSomething(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this in your index.php:

`<div id="result"><?php include "process.php"?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it.

Either use ajax to call your process.php (I'd recommend [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) -- it's very easy to send ajax calls and do stuff based on the results.) and then use javascript to change the form.

Or have the php code that creates the form be the same php code that form submits to, and then output different things based on if there are get parameters. (Edit: MonkeyZeus gave you specifics on how to do this.)